# Rooting android using kingo root

Tags: rooting, root-access

So I was trying to root my samsung android 4.4.2 using the software kingo root.

I first connected it to my pc and then began the rooting process. After it began, the pc app of kingo root was blank and showing no progress bar but i was able to see that it was connecting to the internet, after sone time, it stopped communicating with internet and an app was installed on my phone 'Kingo root'.

I then checked using a software if my phone was rooted but it showed that the phone was not rooted. Also, I couldn't find any SuperSU app on my phone.

My question is, when will i get to know that the rooting process has finished? Also, how do i reinitiate the rooting process given the current scenario of my phone?
Thanks

Comment: I don't recommend using kingo root there was security concerns in the past you don't say your which is your device but i would recommend going to xda-developers forums and search for an more trustworthy way to root

Comment: What type of Samsung do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Use **framaroot**. It's far better than kingoroot. Also kingoroot have some security issues too.

**I. Before You Begin:**

1. This will void the warranty of your device. However, you can reinstate the warranty by unrooting your device if there’s any unrooting procedure available.
2. This only works for some of the android devices.

**II. Downloading Required Files:**

1. [Framaroot APK](https://framarootappdownload.net/)

**III. Rooting Your Android Device (Framaroot Method):**

1. Once it’s been downloaded, head to *Menu>>Settings>>Security* on your device and enable the Unknown sources option.
2. Open the File Manager app on your device and install the app you downloaded earlier to your device.
3. Once the app’s been installed, launch it from your App Drawer.
4. Select Install SuperSU from the first dropdown menu.
5. As for selecting the exploit (there’re three, Sam, Frodo and Aragorn and I personally wish there should be Gollum too ;)), head to this page and see what exploit works for your device. Once you find it out, tap on it in the app.
6. The app should begin rooting your device, shouldn’t take too long to finish.
7. Reboot your device once it’s been rooted.
8. Voila !! You’re done!

You’ve successfully rooted your Android device using the Framaroot app and you should now be able to see the SuperSU app from your App Drawer!

Hope this will help you !! Happy Rooting.

Comment: It's far better according to who?

Comment: According to a lot of android enthusiasts.

Comment: Citation needed. I would you are affiliated with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Success of rooting process depends on version of your system and model of your phone.
I rooted my Samsung Galaxy by installing apk directly on my phone.
You can try using Master Root (English version) from this site: http://www.nextwap.net/mobile/vE4C-rxxce/root_master__english_version_.html You just need to install then click the button - it worked in my case.
After that I recommend installing SuperSU from Google Play.
If you want to check phone for root, there's root checker app in google play